# Postgres GIN index not used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have added multiple GIN indices to a table in Postgres that is frequently searched using wildcard queries (`LIKE '%foo%'`). When looking at slow queries, which I log, I noticed that the GIN indices are not used. The indices are as follows:

```
+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| schemaname | tablename           | indexname                           | tablespace | indexdef                                                                                                          |
|------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| public     | person_affiliations | person_affiliations_pkey            | <null>     | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_affiliations_pkey ON public.person_affiliations USING btree (id)                       |
| public     | persons             | persons_pkey                        | <null>     | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX persons_pkey ON public.persons USING btree (id)                                               |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_status_lower         | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_status_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(status) gin_trgm_ops)                 |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_email_lower          | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_email_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(email) gin_trgm_ops)                   |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_mathreviews_id_lower | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_mathreviews_id_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(mathreviews_id) gin_trgm_ops) |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_zbmath_id_lower      | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_zbmath_id_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(zbmath_id) gin_trgm_ops)           |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_orcid_lower          | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_orcid_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(orcid) gin_trgm_ops)                   |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_homepage_url_lower   | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_homepage_url_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(homepage_url) gin_trgm_ops)     |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_twitter_url_lower    | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_twitter_url_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(twitter_url) gin_trgm_ops)       |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_facebook_url_lower   | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_facebook_url_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(facebook_url) gin_trgm_ops)     |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_linkedin_url_lower   | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_linkedin_url_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(linkedin_url) gin_trgm_ops)     |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_address_line_lower   | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_address_line_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(address_line) gin_trgm_ops)     |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_address_zip_lower    | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_address_zip_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(address_zip) gin_trgm_ops)       |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_address_city_lower   | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_address_city_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(address_city) gin_trgm_ops)     |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_given_name_lower     | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_given_name_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(given_name) gin_trgm_ops)         |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_surname_lower        | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_surname_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(surname) gin_trgm_ops)               |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_prefix_lower         | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_prefix_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(prefix) gin_trgm_ops)                 |
| public     | persons             | idx_gin_person_name_lower           | <null>     | CREATE INDEX idx_gin_person_name_lower ON public.persons USING gin (lower(name) gin_trgm_ops)                     |
+------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The query itself is generated by an application that I don't fully control. It takes this shape that I want to optimize for:

```
explain analyze select "persons"."status", "persons"."prefix", "persons"."given_name", "persons"."surname", "persons"."email", "persons"."address_city", "persons"."id", "persons"."image", 
 "persons"."address_country"
 from "persons"
 where (
   LOWER("persons"."status") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."email") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."mathreviews_id") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."zbmath_id") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."orcid") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."homepage_url") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."twitter_url") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."facebook_url") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."linkedin_url") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."address_line") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."address_zip") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."address_city") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."given_name") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."surname") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."prefix") LIKE '%foo%' or 
   LOWER("persons"."name") LIKE '%foo%'
 )
 order by "persons"."id"
 asc limit 25
```

which results in

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                      >
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
| Limit  (cost=0.29..11.14 rows=25 width=83) (actual time=28.903..83.150 rows=2 loops=1)                                                                                                                          >
|   ->  Index Scan using persons_pkey on persons  (cost=0.29..4222.44 rows=9722 width=83) (actual time=28.902..83.145 rows=2 loops=1)                                                                             >
|         Filter: ((lower(status) ~~ '%foo%'::text) OR (lower(email) ~~ '%foo%'::text) OR (lower(mathreviews_id) ~~ '%foo%'::text) OR (lower(zbmath_id) ~~ '%foo%'::text) OR (lower(orcid) ~~ '%foo%'::text) OR (l>
|         Rows Removed by Filter: 20270                                                                                                                                                                           >
| Planning Time: 0.311 ms                                                                                                                                                                                         >
| Execution Time: 83.190 ms                                                                                                                                                                                       >
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

I would have expected the query plan to do a Bitmap Heap Scan using the GIN indices I defined. Why is this not the case? Are there other settings I could tweak or indices I could add to improve the performance of this particular query?

Comment: Because 15 index scans are slower than a single index scan - especially on such a small table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so the `limit` is to blame? when leaving out `limit 25` i actually get a planning time of 0.3ms and execution time of 3.7ms, all while using the GIN bitmap indices as I thought it would.

Comment: I misread the previous comment; the limit has nothing to do with the table, but the _result_ size of course. however i noticed that playing around with the limit size i could see that the index is used starting at roughly 6000 entries. I am unsure of the exact heuristics use to optimize the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

For these queries you must build index on UPPER(column) and build gin-index on built upper-col index. Then on queries you will have to use statements like:
where UPPER(column) LIKE UPPER('%string%')